# problem exporting eps figures since mathematica 10

Tags: export, text, eps-format

I am having trouble when exporting eps figures since I have upgraded to mathematica 10.0 in linux.

Basically the text in the frame label and in the frameticks come out bad. The letters are much to close to each other. They are almost on top of each other.

For instance when I plot

```
ListPlot[{{0, 0}, {0.1, 0.1}}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{{{0.04, 0.04}, {0.08, 2.25}}, 
    None}, {{{0.04, 0.04}, {0.08, 2.25}}, None}}, FrameLabel -> {"x Axis", "y Axis"}]
```

The first image is exported as an eps then converted to png with 
convert -density 300 Test.eps Testeps.png
[image]

The second image is exported as a pdf then converted to png with 
convert -density 300 Test.pdf Testpdf.png
[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: It has been discussed quite a few times here already. What seems to be the case is that pdf export works much better since V10 and also much better than eps export. If you need to get a good-looking eps image, export to pdf (with Export command, not from the menu) first and then convert pdf to eps with a third party tool. I use "pdftops -eps Something.pdf" under linux to do that.

Comment: And note that if your purpose in exporting to `.eps` is to include the plot in a $\LaTeX$ document, just export it as `.pdf` and use `pdflatex` rather than `latex` to process the document.

Comment: @murray: A good point indeed, in general! May, however, not work with submitting papers if the journals require the figures to be in .eps.

Comment: thanks for the advice. I indeed need an eps for submitting papers. I will make a pdf and convert it or reinstall mathematica 9. 
I nevertheless hope that Wolfram will do something about this issue...

Answer (score 1):

```
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "All.jpg"], %, 
  ImageResolution -> 150, "CompressionLevel" -> 0];
```

Using this export command I got good looking plots on Windows. It may work on your operating system too.

For eps:

```
Export[SystemDialogInput["FileSave", "All.eps"], %%, 
  ImageResolution -> 150, "CompressionLevel" -> 0];
```

[image]

You can experiment with resolution, etc.

This is my first answer so if there is any mistake please pardon me.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The problem was actually fixed with mathematica 10.2.